# I have a list of ID Keys in a spreadsheet that I need to search on a webpage - How do I automate it?

Tags: excel, vba, uipath

I have a list of about 16,000 keys in a spreadsheet that I need to search on a webpage and then screenshot. Is it feasible to write a macro to get that done? It would also be great if I could put something in the macro that snags a date of birth about halfway down the webpage and copies that beside the key.

Comment: You will need to put a lot more work into this question before it can be answered.  VBA can search a webpage.  I do not know what you mean by a screenshot but the answer is probably "No".  Your second sentence implies one date of birth per web page while the first sentence states one webpage.  I suggest deleting this question before it is closed as too vague.  Research reading web pages.  Research how you will recognise the data of birth  Try to develop some code.  You will then be ready to ask a question if necessary.

Comment: Agree with Tony. Easily done in UiPath. But you need to massivly improve yout question before. Not sure what you mean with date of birth.